# Correlated Subquery is working in MySQL but not returning results in Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

EDITED: Put in data as a table instead of screenshot

Somewhat similar to another question I had but for a class project we are using this query:

```
 SELECT     E1.EmployeeID, E1.FirstName, E1.LastName 
 FROM       EMPLOYEE E1 
 WHERE      EXISTS 
      (SELECT    C1.LastName 
      FROM       CUSTOMER C1 
      WHERE      E1.LastName = C1.LastName 
      AND        E1.FirstName = C1.FirstName);
```

which works in MySQL and returns 3 rows. However, it doesn't return any results in Oracle despite both databases having the same data. Oracle doesn't give an error message it just says "No items to display."

As far as I can tell, the data is the same in both databases and should return the four rows that appear in both the Customer and Employee tables. I would really appreciate if someone could point out why they'd have different results.

Data below:

```
 | EmployeeID | LastName  | FirstName |
 |------------|-----------|-----------|
 | 1          | Bibler    | Karl      |
 | 2          | Chagoya   | Cody      |
 | 3          | Ney       | Treyvor   |
 | 4          | Logue     | Nathan    |
 | 5          | Carrillo  | Francisco |
 | 6          | Centeno   | Paulina   |
 | 7          | Kruk      | Christy   |
 | 8          | Montana   | Tony      |
 | 9          | Lara      | John      |
 | 10         | Chaves    | Pancho    |
 | 11         | Smith     | Yazmin    |
 | 12         | Garcia    | Lydia     |
 | 13         | Smith     | Will      |
 | 14         | Lopez     | Jennifer  |
 | 15         | Oneal     | Shaq\`    |
 | 16         | Rose      | Derrick   |
 | 17         | Williams  | Serena    |
 | 18         | Basseti   | Feddy     |
 | 19         | James     | Lebran    |
 | 20         | Fernandez | Vincent   |
```

and Customer:

```
 | lastname | firstname |
 |----------|-----------|
 | Bibler   | Karl      |
 | Chagoya  | Cody      |
 | William  | Thomas    |
 | Logue    | Nathan    |
 | etc      | etc       |
```

Both have 20 rows but three of these rows at the top should be the only ones returning.

Comment: i doubt that it does  not give an error  E2.LastName  is unknown to both databases, besides also provide data to reprodice your problem https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I apologize that was a bad copy/paste by me. in the sql code it is C1.LastName

Comment: Please add data as text not as image see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @nbk I added the data in table markdown format. hopefully that is ok. sorry for the screenshot links.

Answer (score 0):

When i ran a SELECT * query on the employee table it showed that the FirstName and LastName columns were much wider. Somehow, these columns had empty spaces after the names so they weren't registering as the same data as the customer table.

Using the TRIM function I was able to get the results I needed.

```
 SELECT     E1.EmployeeID, E1.FirstName, E1.LastName 
 FROM       EMPLOYEE E1 
 WHERE      EXISTS 
      (SELECT    C1.LastName 
      FROM       CUSTOMER C1 
      WHERE      TRIM(E1.LastName) = TRIM(C1.LastName) 
      AND        TRIM(E1.FirstName) = TRIM(C1.FirstName));
```